# SaveEventually offline behavior

Tags: ios, parsing, save, parse-platform

The app I am currently developing requires offline functionality. Unfortunately in the last few days we tried to use the app with no connection and we noticed something strange.
When we try to use `saveEventually` we see the following debug trace in the log:

> 2014-07-19 18:00:00.079 BallisticBall[2371:8837] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x15dbc500
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=api.parse.com/2/create, NSErrorFailingURLKey=api.parse.com/2/create, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSUnderlyingError=0x1ba79d20 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}
>   (Code: 100, Version: 1.2.18)
>   2014-07-19 18:00:00.082 BallisticBall[2371:5907] Attempt at runEventually command timed out. Waiting 600.000000 seconds. 5 retries remaining.

I waited for ten minutes and a new entry appeared in the log:

> Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1009 "The Internet connection appears to be offline." UserInfo=0x15dce680
>   {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=api.parse.com/2/create, NSErrorFailingURLKey=api.parse.com/2/create, NSLocalizedDescription=The Internet connection appears to be offline., NSUnderlyingError=0x15ddfc50 "The Internet connection appears to be offline."}
>   (Code: 100, Version: 1.2.18)
>   2014-07-19 18:10:00.103 BallisticBall[2371:5907] Attempt at runEventually command timed out. Waiting 600.000000 seconds. 4 retries remaining.

Is this the expected behavior? If users are running the app for longer than one hour, what will happen after the last attempt? Will the record be discarded or saved in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

SaveEventually works also when you are offline, also refer to documentation  "[Saving Objects Offline"](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-saving/iOS) ,
you may also test it by being offline and after saving objects you can find them in application directory structure 
`(Library/Private Documents/Parse/Command Cache)`,
you will notice every unsaved object is there as a file waiting to be dispatched when you are back online.

Comment: Assuming the user has no connection for longer than an hour, what will happen after the first 5 attempts? Does parse retry after a certain timeout or stops trying?

Comment: saveEventually stores it in file offline which gets processed once connectivity is back up , saveInBackground I am not sure about , guaranteed offline is saveEventualy from documentation

Comment: It doesn't save it when internet is back up, so that is incorrect information - it still waits four the time period to expire and queues all the other saveventuallys behind it which is horrible behaviour.